# JOINS in Lucene

Tags: join, lucene

Is there any way to implement JOINS in Lucene?

Comment: Lucene isn't a relational database. What do you mean?

Comment: @skaffman - I'm using Lucene as a full text search engine for an MS SQL DB.  It occurs to me that I could do away with the SQL DB altogether if I simply stored all the data in fields within Lucene.  However, to do this I would need some way of joining docs together.

Comment: Norris You can't do that, you will need to flatten the relationship, since lucene does not handle relations between documents.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do a generic join by hand - run two searches, get all results (instead of top N), 
sort them on your join key and intersect two ordered lists. But that's gonna thrash your heap real hard (**if** the lists even fit in it).

There are possible optimizations, but under very specific conditions.
I.e. - you do a self-join, and only use (random access) `Filters` for filtering, no `Queries`. Then you can manually iterate terms on your two join fields (in parallel), intersect docId lists for each term, filter them - and here's your join.

There's an approach handling a popular use-case of simple parent-child relationships with relatively small numer of children per-document - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-2454
Unlike the flattening method mentioned by @ntziolis, this approach correctly handles cases like: have a number of resumes, each with multiple work_experience children, and try finding someone who worked at company NNN in year YYY. If simply flattened, you'll get back resumes for people that worked for NNN in any year & worked somewhere in year YYY.

An alternative for handling simple parent-child cases is to flatten your doc, indeed, but ensure values for different children are separated by a big posIncrement gap, and then use `SpanNear` query to prevent your several subqueries from matching across children. There was a few-years old LinkedIn presentation about this, but I failed to find it.

Answer (score 12):

You can also use the new BlockJoinQuery; I described it in a blog post here:

http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/01/searching-relational-content-with.html

Comment: One of the problems with the BlockJoinQuery as I understand it is that Block require a full reindex of the elements within the block when one of the contained parent or children changes. This is exactly the kind of thing I would want to avoid with a "join-concept". So a BlockJoinQuery creates more query flexibility but doesn't offer a more atomic storage concept.

Answer (score 3):

**Lucene does not support relationships between documents**, but a join is nothing else but a specific combination of multiple `AND` within parenthesis, but you will need to **flatten the relationship first**.

Sample (SQL => Lucene):

SQL:

```
SELECT Order.* FROM Order
JOIN Customer ON Order.CustomerID = Customer.ID
WHERE Customer.Name = 'SomeName'
AND Order.Nr = 400
```

Lucene:
Make sure you have all the neccessary fields and their respective values on the document like:
Customer.Name => "Customer_Name" and
Order.Nr => "Order_Nr"

The query would then be:

```
( Customer_Name:"SomeName" AND Order_Nr:"400" )
```

Answer (score 3):

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2272

Answer (score 3):

Use **joinutil**. It allows query time joins.

See: http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/join/org/apache/lucene/search/join/JoinUtil.html

Answer (score 2):

A little late but you could use Package org.apache.lucene.search.join : https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_3_0/join/org/apache/lucene/search/join/package-summary.html

From their documentation:

> The index-time joining support joins while searching, where joined
>   documents are indexed as a single document block using
>   IndexWriter.addDocuments().

```
   String fromField = "from"; // Name of the from field
   boolean multipleValuesPerDocument = false; // Set only yo true in the case when your fromField has multiple values per document in your index
   String toField = "to"; // Name of the to field
   ScoreMode scoreMode = ScoreMode.Max // Defines how the scores are translated into the other side of the join.
   Query fromQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("content", searchTerm)); // Query executed to collect from values to join to the to values

   Query joinQuery = JoinUtil.createJoinQuery(fromField, multipleValuesPerDocument, toField, fromQuery, fromSearcher, scoreMode);
   TopDocs topDocs = toSearcher.search(joinQuery, 10); // Note: toSearcher can be the same as the fromSearcher
   // Render topDocs...
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some implementations on the top of Lucene that make those kind of joins among several different indexes possible. Numere (http://numere.stela.org.br/) enable that and make it possible to get results as a RDBMS result set.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example [Numere provides an easy way to extract analytical data from Lucene indexes](http://numere.stela.org.br)

```
select a.type, sum(a.value) as "sales", b.category, count(distinct b.product_id) as "total"
from a (index)
inner join b (index) on (a.seq_id = b.seq_id)
group by a.type, b.category
order by a.type asc, b.category asc


    Join join = RequestFactory.newJoin();

    // inner join a.seq_id = b.seq_id

    join.on("seq_id", Type.INTEGER).equal("seq_id", Type.INTEGER);

    // left
    {
        Request left = join.left();
        left.repository(UtilTest.getPath("indexes/md/master"));
        left.addColumn("type").textType().asc();
        left.addMeasure("value").alias("sales").intType().sum();
    }

    // right
    {
        Request right = join.right();
        right.repository(UtilTest.getPath("indexes/md/detail"));
        right.addColumn("category").textType().asc();
        right.addMeasure("product_id").intType().alias("total").count_distinct();
    }

    Processor processor = ProcessorFactory.newProcessor();
    try {
        ResultPacket result = processor.execute(join);
        System.out.println(result);
    } finally {
        processor.close();
    }
```

Result:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<DATAPACKET Version="2.0">
  <METADATA>
    <FIELDS>
      <FIELD attrname="type" fieldtype="string" WIDTH="20" />
      <FIELD attrname="category" fieldtype="string" WIDTH="20" />
      <FIELD attrname="sales" fieldtype="i8" />
      <FIELD attrname="total" fieldtype="i4" />
    </FIELDS>
    <PARAMS />
  </METADATA>
  <ROWDATA>
    <ROW type="Book" category="stand" sales="127003304" total="2" />
    <ROW type="Computer" category="eletronic" sales="44765715835" total="896" />
    <ROW type="Meat" category="food" sales="3193526428" total="110" />
```

... continue