# How to sort solr results by foreign id field

Tags: sorting, join, solr, lucene

I have documents with the following fields:

```
id
name
parent
color
```

The parent field is an ID of another document.
I want to select all documents where the color is red and sort the results by the name of the parent.
Can it be done in solr?

Comment: Lucene is not a relational database, and does not support joins.  Generally, you'll need to join by hand or change the representation of your data.  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497861/joins-in-lucene) might be of interest for a few strategies on that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below Solr query for selecting all documents whose color is red and sort them by the parent.

q=color:red&sort=name desc

If you want to sort it by the name of the record the parentID is pointing to, then you would have to use [Solr JOIN's](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join) or De-normalize the data by adding the parent's name to your document.

Comment: De-normalize isn't an option currently. If you can show how this can be solved with the solr join I'll be happy to accept the answer. As far as I know the join functionality can't solve such queries.