# doing a self join hibernate-search

Tags: hibernate-search, self-join

i have a question regarding hibernate search (or lucene which is under the hood).

say i have a table like this:

- ...ID..WHO..ITEM...PRICE
- 001 |joey   |    ipod       |100.00
- 002 |joey   |        .....tv      | 200.00

i want to be able to find a person who has bought an ipod for $100 and a tv for $200. 
i.e user would enter something like "item=ipod price = 100 item=tv price=200" and it would return "joey" as well as item/price details.

in sql it would be something like....

```
   select * from tbl a
    join tbl b 
    on a.PERSON_ID = b.PERSON_ID
    where (a.item='ipod' and a.price='100.00') 
    and (b.item='tv' and b.price='200.00');
```

is there anyway to do this in hibernate search/lucene?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that there is no self-join functionality in HSearch/Lucene. You find some more information here - [JOINS in Lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497861/joins-in-lucene)